# Nest js service is undefined, possibly due to circular dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have 2 modules `ZohoModule` and `TaskModule`. Zoho module has a `ZohoService`.

Task module has two services `UtilityTaskService` and `TasksService`
both are added as task module providers and exported in task module.

My first question is: Why do I have to add `forwardref` in `UtilityTaskService` for `TasksService`? If I remove `forwardref` it gives me a dependency error, but both the services are part of same module.

Second the severe one whenever I am calling a method in  `UtilityTaskService` from `ZohoService` and `UtilityTaskService` is calling `TasksService` all the service in `TasksService` are becoming undefined.

eg -

ZohoService.ts in Zoho module:

```
@Injectable()
export class ZohoService {
  constructor(
    private readonly utilityService: UtilityTaskService,
  ) { }

  callUtilityService(){
      this.utilityService.validate();
}
```

UtilityTaskService.ts in TaskModule:
(Why do I have to add `forwardref`  when TasksService is part of the same TaskModule?)

```
@Injectable()
export class UtilityTaskService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => TasksService))
    private readonly taskService: TasksService,
  ) { }

  async validate() {
   await this.taskService.create();
}
```

TasksService.ts in TaskModule:

```
@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('TaskType')
    private taskTypeModel: Model<ITaskTypeSchema>,
    private redisService: RedisService,
  ) { }

async create() {
  this.redis.fetchData();
  this.taskTypeModel.find();
}
```

Both Redis and task typemodel are giving error "cannot read property 'fetchData' of undefined, can't read property 'find' of undefined".

But when I call Tasks service from another service it works fine.

My TaskModule.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([
    { name: 'TaskType', schema: TaskTypeSchema },
  ]),
  TypeOrmModule.forFeature([CounterEntity]),
  // RedisModule,
  forwardRef(() => RedisModule),
  ],
  providers: [
    TasksService,
    UtlityTaskService,
  ],
  exports: [TasksService, UtilityTaskService],
  controllers: [TasksController],
})
```

I am stuck here for 2 days.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you should forwardRef your `RedisService` in Tasks service and then remove the forwardRef from TaskModule and UtilityTaskService.

Comment: Have you found what caused the error ?

Comment: @mentorgashi Yes , so the error was let's say service A uses service B and service B uses Service A , during build process the service which loads first tries to call another service which is unavailable. This caused the undefined error. The soultion is to make a common service which usses both the service.